# Verifying a method called downstream in Mockito (through private void overloaded method)

Tags: java, testing, mockito, overloading, private

I'm having trouble figuring out how to test if my method `foo(int length, String name)` is being called.

My complications :

1. I have an overloaded void method, plus it's private (I cannot change it from private although that would work, for this purpose)
2. It has a public method downstream from the private method I could try to test (Bar.bar()), but not sure how to test it properly with Mockito
3. I'm trying to test for customer length over 5 and under 5, to make sure it hits the private `foo` method either once if it's over, or none if it's under. Either way, it will be hitting public `foo(Customer)` once.
4. Would rather not use Powermockito for simplicity if possible

```html
public class Foo {

  public void foo(Customer customer) {
    if (customer.length() > 5) {
       foo(customer.length(), customer.name());
    } else {
      return
    }
  }
  
  //Private overloaded method 
  private void foo(int length, String name) {
    bar.bar();
  }
  
}


public class Bar {

  public Order bar(int length, String name) {
    barProcessing(...)
  }

  private Order barProcessing(...) {
    ...calling another Bar method
  }
  
}
```

What I've tried so far :

Mocking Foo and Bar classes plus doing a bunch of `when()` statements, then doing...

- verify(foo, times(1)).foo(any(Customer.class)); (WORKS)
- verify(bar, times(1)).bar(any(Integer.class), any(String.class)); (FAILS, returns 0)
- doCallRealMethod().when(foo).foo(any(Customer.class)); (WORKS)
- foo.foo(Customer); (WORKS)
- BDDMockito.given(bar.bar("123", date)).willReturn(Order); (FAILS)
- BDDMockito.then(bar).should().bar(any(Integer.class), any(String.class)); (FAILS)

Pretty stumped here, with the addition of my complications. I'm still new to Mockito, open to any new suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. In general, test the behavior of public API. Private methods are an implementation detail; test them indirectly through calling the public methods.
2. You're on the right track with mocking `bar` and confirming that it's used *somewhere* by `foo(Customer)`. You said you've "tried" mocking it, but not how you actually did that. Your #2 and #6 should generally work; actually *debug* your code and check whether `bar.bar()` is really being invoked as well as whether your mock is being injected into your `Foo`.

### Edit

After some clarification, it seems you misunderstand when to use mocks in testing. You use mocks specifically for the items that you are *not* testing; if you're testing `Foo` but then mock it, you're not testing the actual behavior! Instead, mock the `Bar` and provide it however you would mock a real `Bar` (such as passing it as constructor parameter).

Comment: I'll give it another try! I was mocking it like ```Foo foo = mock(Foo.class)``` and ```Bar bar = mock(Bar.class)``` and then adding all my required values for the method to work like ```when(foo.name()).thenReturn("Bob")```. Good to know that it is possible at the very least, and might just be down to my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @Jason If you are trying to _test_ your `Foo` class, you don't mock it. You create a real instance but mock the _other_ objects involved.